# StyleCop header documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

Just starting to use StyleCop and I've encountered a couple of issues and I can't manage to fix it.

First example is my main, it throws me a SA1612 error says that tags isn't matching.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Main Method to run the program
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UserInput">function that gets the input</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserInput();
        }
```

Second example is my function, it says that documentation isn't containing all param tags, I suppose. SA1611

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets by boolean if the input is Binary and 7 digits long
        /// <param name="num">integer type a number user enters</param>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True or false</returns>
        private static Boolean LegitBinary(int num)
        {
            while (num != 0)
            {
                if (num % 10 != 0 && num % 10 != 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                num /= 10;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I got same error as in the second example on almost all my functions. Would really appreciate a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First example:**
Parameter is named `UserInput` which does not match the actual name is `args`.

**Second example:**
Section `<param>...</param>` should not be enclosed in `<summary>...</summary>` section.